# Get Changes Between Builds from VSO API using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi package

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm working on my app which gets data via VSO API. I'm using

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient

class to get the data. There is the

> GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync

method which would be a great help for me, but there is something strange.

When I call this method I get the following exception:

```
{
   "Method not found: 
  'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Change>> 
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClientBase.GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync(
    System.String, 
    System.Nullable`1<Int32>,
    System.Nullable`1<Int32>, 
    System.Nullable`1<Int32>, 
    System.Object, 
    System.Threading.CancellationToken)'."
}
```

I did the following so far to solve the problem:

- At first I thought something went wrong during compile. I compiled the code in release and in debug many times but the problem was not solved. I still have the issue.
- I have checked the references, all of the projects related to work with data coming from VSO have the same references. Did not help.
- I decompiled the binary but it has the code in place

The strange is that there is another method,

> GetBuildsAsync

which I use and it works well, and they are in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have found what is the root of the problem above. I had two version of the packages installed and it seems the references were messed up. I have removed and reinstalled the packages below. Now it is working, at least the request hits the server but I always get that error there is no earlier build.

- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client